# Get all unique combinations for x amount of spots with same options each time

Tags: php, algorithm, loops, unique, combinations

I'm not sure about the right terminology, but I need a program that gives all unique combinations for a fixed amount of options with a variable amount of spots, as such:

```
options: "a", "b", "c"  
max spots: 3

output:
a 
a a 
a b
a c
a a a 
a a b
a b b 
a a c
a c c 
a b c
b
b b 
b c
b b b
b b c 
b c c 
c
c c 
c c c
```

I currently have this bit of code, but I've got no idea how to make it variably scalable for more spots. Normally it puts the combination inside an array, instead of printing it and that array is later used for other calculations.

```
$options = array("a", "b", "c");

for ($x = 0; $x < 3; $x++) {
    print "$options[$x]\n";
    for ($y = $x; $y < 3; $y++) {
        print "$options[$x] $options[$y]\n";
        for ($z = $y; $z < 3; $z++) {
            print "$options[$x] $options[$y] $options[$z]\n";
        }
    }
}
```

My other somewhat successful attempt was putting the generated combination into an array, sorting that array, turning the array into a string and checking whether the string already exists in the array with all the accepted combination strings. This seems terribly inefficient and I was hoping if there's a better way. I'd strongly prefer to not use external functions, because I want to get better at PHP and loops and such.

Comment: It's not that hard if you use recursion.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to programming so hadn't heard about it. I'll see how far I get.

Comment: Ok since nobody answered, now I can show you how...

Comment: Wow, thanks allot, didn't expect it could be so simple, but it's very effective. Those recursive functions will surely be a handy tool in my other projects. :-)

Comment: A generator function is also a new concept to me, so I'll look into its use and benefits once I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get there using recursion (this assumes you only have unique characters in the option array, if not you would have to do that first):

```
function printCombinations(&$options, $max, $index = 0, $prefix = '') {
    if ($prefix)
        print "$prefix\n";
    if ($max <= 0)
        return;
    for ($i = $index; $i < count($options); $i++) {
        printCombinations($options, $max - 1, $i, $prefix . ' ' . $options[$i]);
    }
}
```

You would call it like this: `printCombinations(['a', 'b', 'c'], 3);`. Because we are kind of enumerating the combinations we are not getting any duplicates (unless $options has duplicates).

This will give you `a b` but not `b a`, so the elements have to be taken in order, this seems to be what your list indicated. The call above should give you exactly your list (in slightly different order).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generator implementation that doesn't require references.

```
function permutations($alphabet, $max, $prefix = '') {
    $alphabetRemaining = $alphabet;

    if ($prefix) {
        yield $prefix;
    }

    if ($max <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    foreach ($alphabet as $alpha) {
        yield from permutations($alphabetRemaining, $max - 1, $prefix . $alpha);
        array_shift($alphabetRemaining);
    }
}

foreach (permutations(["a", "b", "c"], 3) as $perm) {
    echo "$perm\n";
}
```

### Output

```
a
aa
aaa
aab
aac
ab
abb
abc
ac
acc
b
bb
bbb
bbc
bc
bcc
c
cc
ccc
```

If you want *all possible permutations* you should use this instead.

```
function permutations($alphabet, $max, $prefix = '') {
    $alphabetRemaining = $alphabet;

    if ($prefix) {
        yield $prefix;
    }

    if ($max <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    foreach ($alphabet as $alpha) {
        yield from permutations($alphabetRemaining, $max - 1, $prefix . $alpha);
    }
}

foreach (permutations(["a", "b", "c"], 3) as $perm) {
    echo "$perm\n";
}
```

### Output

```
a
aa
aaa
aab
aac
ab
aba
abb
abc
ac
aca
acb
acc
b
ba
baa
bab
bac
bb
bba
bbb
bbc
bc
bca
bcb
bcc
c
ca
caa
cab
cac
cb
cba
cbb
cbc
cc
cca
ccb
ccc
```

Comment: No references, but also not more efficient. References are better than copying the whole array and then shifting it. Right?

Comment: No, not necessarily.

Comment: @maraca PHP references are not pointers, and PHP variables are not simple lumps of memory. PHP references are confusing, frequently cause code to misbehave, and generally don't have the performance benefit people assume they do. This comes with the caveat that many PHP _builtin_ functions that use references do have all those benefits because it's compiled C full of optimizations and actual pointers in the background.

Comment: @Sammitch not if you don't modify them. There is no reason to copy everything on each call.

Comment: PHP is copy-on-write, just FYI.

Comment: @maraca what Sherif said.

Comment: @Sherif OK, thanks for the info, still array_shift is O(n). It's nice to have a generator, yes. But "that doesn't require references" as if it were a good thing is what I don't agree with, because time complexity of your algorithm is worse.

Comment: No, it's the same.

Comment: You could just remove the & from my algorithm and get one without references. array_shift is modifying the array. And no this implementation is definitely slower. array_shift is almost never a good idea.

Comment: Actually, if you want to get technical about it your implementation is slower because you call `count()` with every iteration of the loop. Though using `array_shift` will have virtually no effect on speed here. So they're the same in terms of time complexity. You can keep trying to tell me it's slower, but I'm afraid that's provably wrong. Why you're trying so desperately to convince me of something that's factually wrong is beyond me. There's nothing inherently wrong with either implementation. The only *real* difference is this one returns results rather than print them directly.